# imagecreatefrompng() inside for() loop?

Tags: php

```
$fpos = 50;
for ($i = 21; $i >= 0; $i--)
{
    if($array[$i]==1 && $arccount<4)
    {
        $arccount = $arccount + 1;
        $path = "../sig/arc/" . $i . ".png";
        $arcimg = imagecreatefrompng($path);
        imagecopy($img, $arcimg, 400, 50, 0, 0, 200, $fpos);
        $fpos = $fpos+50;
    }
}
```

Instead of printing thrice, it only prints the last value it finds true, aka 1. So from the 21 pos vector where pos 1, 2 and 3 are 1 and the rest to 21 are 0, it will print only 1.png . If I change v[1] to 0, it will print v[2] and so on. Why?

arccount is nulled and the purpose is to only print the last 3 images from the end

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are changing the src_h parameter with your $fpos argument. I think you probably meant to change the dest_y parameter.

Try:
    imagecopy($img, $arcimg, 400, $fpos, 0, 0, 200, 50);

Comment: yep, just noticed before refreshing. I'm a dumbass